# Add people result block to a site's osssearchresults.aspx result page

Tags: 2013, search-results, search-scope, enterprise-search, people-search

I'm attempting to add a result block (via query rule) to the top of the osssearchresults.aspx result page for contextual site searches that provides the same data as a Person Result would from the "Local People Results" result source.

However whenever the "u" parameter of the query string is present the search results web part seems to disregard the fact I want to return results from outside of the contextual location.  If I remove the "u" parameter I see the behavior I'm looking for with the exception of the results no longer being scoped to that site.  I'm trying to avoid modifying the osssearchresults.aspx if I have to.  Any ideas?

Is there a way to include results from a separate result source within the scoped osssearchresults.aspx results page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SP.SE EGR.

Never change the layouts page - better create a search center and adjust it there. 
On the other hand, People Results are not site specific - I doubt that it works with "this site" scope.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for some time I've come to the conclusion that due to the "u" parameter being passed to the Search Results Webpart users will never be returned because they do not live within that site scope.  This can be replicated in the main search center by passing the "u" parameter with a site url.